# Is there a way to export WooCommerce products without the variations?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, shopify, e-commerce

I am migrating an e-commerce store from Shopify to WooCommerce and I don't want to lose my product reviews.

I've been asked by Stamped to produce a list of all the Shopify product IDs lined up next to their matching WooCommerce IDs.

The issue I'm having is when I export WooCommerce products it features all the variations as well.

I'm trying to find a way to export just the parent product and products without variation so I can get this overall task done.

All I can find is ways to export with variations.

Anyone found a way to deal with this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

On the "Export Products" page in woo, the second field down lets you select which type(s) of products you export. In your case, you'll want the option for "Variable Product". "Product Variations" includes only the 'child products', allowing you to export only the variations.

The first field will let you narrow down the columns exported as well, which *can* speed up the export if you've got tons of variable-type products.

So, if you were to select "ID", "Type", and "Name" for columns and select "Variable Product" then your export will have the product name (or whatever identifying attribute you need) along with the ID to match up with your Shopify ID.

If when you first imported your products you included the Shopify ID as a custom meta field in woo. That could really make your task easy! Good luck!